# Referencing Current Django HttpRequest Instance

Tags: python, django, httprequest

I'm new to python/django and wondering if there is a way to reference the current HttpRequest instance other than passing around the request instance.

For example, in .net I could reference the request instance from any function using:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.
```

Can this be done in django without having to keep putting the request instance as a parameter to other functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in short, no. since django's own session exists inside request any function or class not passed request will not have it in it's scope.